# Equivalent request command for this curl

Tags: python, curl, file-upload, upload, python-requests

I have a curl command which is working fine and uploading the file to the server.

```
curl -v <url> --fail --user <username>:<password> --upload-file filename
```

I have tried the requests module in python. The command I am issuing is

```
fileobj = open('dist\\test.zip', 'rb')
requests.put(__url, data={"upload": "upload"}, files={"archive": ("test.zip", fileobj)}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username,password))
```

the python request is not working and returning `Bad Request`, `error 400`.

What can be the equivalent python command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution to my problem.

```
zip_file = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'rb')
headers = {'content-type': 'application/zip'}
return_val = requests.put(url=url, data=zip_file, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password),headers=header_type)
```